# ObjectDisposedException despite *Include* being used

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, include

In my view model, I 'm doing the following.

```
public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
  using (Context context = new Context())
    Orders = context.Orders
      .Include(order => order.Status).ToList();
}
Order test1 = Orders.First(item => item.Status != null);
Order test2 = Orders.First(item => item.Status != null && item.Status.Id == 1);
```

So I have included the navigational properties and have them there for future use. But if I poke around and unfold the objects being watched, I see that the status actually has no value. It produces the error below.

> '(test1.Status).Orders' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'

Now, It's my understanding that such is the result if I forget to use *Include()* because the entities fall out of scope of the contexts and get disposed. But in this case, they're not and I'm buffed why.

Suggestions? on what I missed?

After I've poked around, I can 't stop but having this impression that the inclusion of the *Status* is correct but that it, in turn, doesn't include the reference back to the original *Order*. I'm a bit confused on how to approach it...

Comment: Are you sure that the items in the database actually have a status? Also, is this code first or database first? And on a side note, use FirstOrDefault() instead of First().

Comment: Yes. I can read them.

Comment: Just use a try...finally.

Comment: @Konrad, can you post your two entities please? For Order and Status.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Sorry, it looks good to me, unless there is something wrong with your model, or a global setting that overrides defaults that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here your `context` has `LazyLoadingEnabled=true` by default, so the `Include` won't set the back reference for each eagerly-loaded `Status`. You can try turning off lazy loading of that context and you'll see the back reference will be also eagerly-loaded correctly:

```
using (Context context = new Context()){
  context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  Orders = context.Orders
                  .Include(order => order.Status).ToList();
}
```

I've just made a simple demo and confirm that it works.

Comment: I'd like to see this demo, because eager loading should (and normally does) set this reference. Why shouldn't it? When I eagerly load such references with lazy loading enabled, I can do anything with them after disposing the context. *Anything* includes code as in the OP.. So I'm afraid your answer isn't correct and something else is going on here.

Comment: @GertArnold eager loading does load `Status` but it does not load `Order` referenced by each Status. Looks like it does not work 2 way for you by default unless lazy loading is disabled. As I said I tested this and the OP also tested (for sure) before accepting this answer. The code is just simple, you can make it yourself.

Comment: Ah, OK, I missed the `(test1.Status).Orders` part (the `Orders`). By disabling lazy loading you get the orders that were populated by relationship fixup, while the collections themselves are not marked as loaded (and, thus, still trigger lazy loading). Good catch!